# Get style from previous span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With jquery, I want to get the rgb color code from the spzn previous to the one that was clicked.

I can get the clicks with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#myDiv :radio").click(function(){
    alert("Got here");
    });
});
```

So, how do I get the rgb code #000000 from the span with class swatchColour_1 prior to the radio button.

There are about 30 li elements for different colors. The only code I can actually change is the very first div with id="myList"

```
<div class="productAttributeList" id="myList" style="">
    <div class="productAttributeRow xx" id="ffb492067dcd98c19b6be89e9230f4fc">
        <div class="productAttributeLabel">
            <label for="06b0854950dd6cc1d296718965c0d36a">
                <span class="required">*</span>
                    <span class="name">Color choice:</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="productAttributeValue">
            <div class="productOptionPickListSwatch">
                <ul>
                    <li class="swatch hasPreview swatchOneColour">
                        <label for="0780a439a3a2ec8492a8772f4f5d739a">
                        <span class="previewContent">
                            <span class="swatchColours swatchOneColour showPreview" title="Black - 070">
                                <span class="swatchColour swatchColour_1" style="background-color:#000000;">&nbsp;</span>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                            <input type="radio" class="validation" name="attribute[119]" value="195" id="0780a439a3a2ec8492a8772f4f5d739a"  />
                            <span class="name">Black - 070</span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
```

.
.
.

Thanks Gary

Comment: _#000000_ is not rgb.

Comment: something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/elen/Y4HSP/ - you missed `input:` and it's better to use `change()` especially if you adding more buttons

Comment: it's easier to use radio button value attribute to store rgb, than find span, however - http://jsfiddle.net/elen/Y4HSP/1/

Comment: Thanks, change is better.

I don't have access to the code that builds the radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#myDiv :radio").click(function(){
    alert($(this).prev("span.previewContent").find(".swatchColour_1").css("background-color"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks great, both answers should work fine. I can only check one though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev), [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) and [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css) methods:

```
$( "#myList input[type=radio]").change(function() {
    var color = $(this).prev().find('.swatchColour_1').css('background-color');
});
```

Or using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) method:

```
var color = $(this).closest('.previewContent')
                   .find('.swatchColour_1')
                   .css('background-color');
```

http://api.jquery.com/